# update to UAP (10.0.16299.0)

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Currently I am using VS2017 Community.
I have downloaded the Windows IoT template for VS2017 community to do UWP programming.

After created the project, when I try to open the XAML file in designer view, I encountered this Message:

visual studio requires a newer version of windows to display this content.
 please update to windows 10 Fall Creator update(10.0.16299.0)

So, I downloaded latest  Win10 SDK

But Now I have this message:

visual studio requires a newer version of windows to display this content.
 please update to UAP (10.0.16299.0)

What I need to do?

Thanks

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/43064/visual-studio-2017-visual-studio-requires-a-newer.html

Comment: Yup, this solved the problem. I change my project to target the Windows version same or lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the VS 2017 (15.4 update) or later to get the Windows 10 Fall Creators Update SDK (16299) integration.

If you have the 15.4 update already, then run the *Visual Studio Installer*, go to the Individual Component tab, and then check the components for 16299. Hit *Modify*.

See [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2017/10/11/windows-10-fall-creators-update-sdk/).

**UPDATE:** For C#/C++ projects, you set which Windows 10 SDK is used by editing the Project Properties and setting the *Target Platform Version* to `10.0.16299.0`. You can also use the "Retarget solution" or "Retarget project" option.

Comment: Thanks for the update,I have updated the VS2017 with the notification it provided such as the yellow flag. It still showed the message. However, when I followed the above link; I changed the project to target the windows version either same or lower, this will solve my problem. This is how it is done: Right click the project and select properties. From there, change the target window version.